# SQL query is correct with one data table, but wrong with another

Tags: sql

I was solving problem 88 on sql-ex.ru but the result was not correct for the second checking data table. The following is the data table scheme:

```
Company(ID_comp, name)
Trip(trip_no, id_comp, plane, town_from, town_to, time_out, time_in)
Passenger(ID_psg, name)
Pass_in_trip(trip_no, date, ID_psg, place)
```

Problem:

Among the clients which only use a single company, find the different passengers who have flown more often than others. Result set: passenger name, number of trips, and company name.

My query to the problem:

```
select distinct t1.name, t.cnt, t4.name company
from (
   select top 1 with ties id_psg, count(t1.trip_no) cnt
   from pass_in_trip t1 
   join trip t2 on t1.trip_no = t2.trip_no
   group by id_psg
   having count(distinct id_comp) = 1
   order by count(t1.trip_no) desc
 ) t
join passenger t1 on t.id_psg = t1.id_psg
join pass_in_trip t2 on t.id_psg = t2.id_psg
join trip t3 on t2.trip_no = t3.trip_no
join company t4 on t3.id_comp = t4.id_comp
```

The following is a message I got after I submitted the query:

**Incorrect.
Your query returned the correct dataset on the first (available) database,    but it returned incorrect dataset on the second checking database.
* Wrong number of records (less by 1)**

The desired result is as followed

```
      name        qty     company
------------------------------------
 Michael Caine |   4   | British_AW
 Mullah Omar   |   4   | British_AW
```

I have got the result after submitting my query, but I still get the "Incorrect" message, which is where I stuck. I don't know exactly why my query failed to produce the correct answer for the second data table. Could anyone please take a look at the problem and the query and let me know what's wrong with the my query? Thank you!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi, Alexander. I have edited the question and included the error message and desired result. I have described the problem and the database scheme at the beginning. My query got the desired result on the first data table, but it failed to generate another correct answer on the second data table. I don't know exactly what happened there so that's why I'm asking if there's anything missing in my query. It would also be appreciated if you have a better answer to the problem.

Comment: It's kind of obscure, isn't it? We don't have the available data, desired output and actual output.
At this point I could ask - maybe the problem expects a wrong answer? I checked that website, and it's so low quality that I wouldn't trust it to be anything precise. And I couldn't get to Problem 88.

Comment: I encountered the same situation before when solving other problems and it turned out I did miss something in my query, so after some improvement I got passed. For this one, the answer on the website could be wrong, but I want to make sure I did everything correctly. If it is not clear for you to debug, it would be appreciated if you could solve the problem (i.e. write a query to get the results) in your way.